# Can't read in file?

Tags: python, anaconda

the files are in the same folder but the file isn't being read in. Looking at SO I thought I could find a solution but not sure.

```
import os
script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__) 
rel_path = "textfile.txt"
abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path)


with open('textfile.txt', 'r') as file:
    text = file.read()
    print(text)
```

I really just want the second half of the code to work, not sure how to get it working. I'm using anaconda. I'm getting no file/dir exists for the .txt file.

Comment: `I really just want the second half of the code to work, not sure how to get it working` this part of your question doesn't explain your issue. What's your expected output? What you are getting? and Mention 1st part and 2nd part as comments in your code.

Comment: @shaikmoeed I'm trying to run the second part. I'm trying to read in the textfile.txt and print out the contents. Very simple, basic stuff. But when I run the command I'm told that No file or directory exists, even though it's in the same folder. Even in Anaconda, if I use os.listdir, I can see the text file in the folder. But when I run the code it isn't able to find it.

Comment: So do you actually use `abs_file_path` as an argument of `open`? You code suggests otherwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

`with open(abs_file_path, 'r') as file:`

Comment: Thanks i see what i did

Comment: Are you running the whole script? @RyanRiis